# Mysql Show Process - Sleep Commands and what to do

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm wondering if There is something that I can do to better get keep my process list clean when initiating commands with MySQL.  Currently I have been seeing a lot of:

`17325      user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1132        NULL`

`17464  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1124        NULL`

`17983  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1078        NULL`

`18113  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1068        NULL`

`18207  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1060        NULL`

`18231  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1058        NULL`

`18353  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1047        NULL`

`18447  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1040        NULL`

`18489  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   1036        NULL`

`23408  user_a  localhost   db_1    Sleep   637         NULL`

Is there something in my phpscript that I can do to clean this up?

Script looks like:
`$q = 'select id from db_1 where fkId=2';
    $ar = mysql_query($q); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qr)){ echo($row['id']; }`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm going to guess that since you have 10 threads there, you're using persistent connections. what do persistent connections do when they're not processing a request? they sleep. so this is normal and does not need cleaning up.

unless you want to disable persistent connections.