# When will the database process killed?

Tags: mysql

I find that mySQL always have many data process here, but I already close the pages I opened. Also, I haven't publish the web online yet, why there is so many process here, and these all process are Command is sleep, What's happen? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+process+sleep

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Show Process - Sleep Commands and what to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574057/mysql-show-process-sleep-commands-and-what-to-do)

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have opened connections. You should close them manually in the application, do not leave them open; or set [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) server variable to close connections automatically.